# Does a continual damage effect stack with itself?

Tags: dnd-5e

This question has to do specifically with the flumph from the Monster Manual. Its Tendrils attack applies a damaging effect that remains until it is saved against. My question is can the effect be applied multiple times or is it restricted to the simple 1d4 acid damage? If it can be applied multiple times, are the saving throws applied individually like most effects or does one successful save remove them all?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been addressed by the [DMG Errata:](http://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/DMG_Errata.pdf)

> **Combining Game Effects.** when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one—apply while the durations of the effects overlap. [...] Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items

Comment: Not exactly perfectly: is the outcome to roll 1d4 twice and take the largest as the most potent or to say they are equally potent and roll 1d4 once?

Comment: @DaleM Equally potent, roll once. Otherwise, you'd *always* roll *all* effects and then take the highest roll - it's possible you'd roll higher on a d4 than you did on a d20.